# Cypress cant find spec files in folder I want

Tags: testing, cypress, cypress-configuration

I made a couple of cypress tests, however I can't seem to make cypress locate the spec files, it only locates the cypress\e2e folders/files (the tutorial folders), when I want them to access the tests\e2e\specs folder

I tried changing the cypress.json by:

```
{
  "pluginsFile": "tests/e2e/plugins/index.js",
  "integrationFolder": "tests" 
}
```

(Also tried "tests/e2e/specs" and "PintAndPillageFrontend/tests/e2e/specs")
but that didn't seem to work

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that sticks out is you have `cypress.json` which is the old way (pre version 10) of configuring, yet the project is obvious structured for the current setup of Cypress.

Therefore, I'm going to recommend that in `cypress.config.js` (which should be in the project root) you add a `specPattern` setting that includes an array of all the paths that may contain a spec you want Cypress to run.

[configuration#e2e](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e)

> **specPattern**   `cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}`
> A String or Array of glob patterns of the test files to load.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
    specPattern: [
      'cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
      'printandpillage/tests/e2e/**/*.cy.js',
      'printandpillage/tests/e2e/**/*test.js',
    ],
  },
})
```

Sticking to one spec naming pattern such as `*.cy.js` will give Cypress and other people more clarity about your tests.